# How to add a table view, and a uibutton as my home page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to implemented an app on phone gap

I have implemented basic app in xcode 4.1 using http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4

I got home page as

---

```
Hey it's phone gap
Dont know how to get started? check
phone gap start
```

---

Now I need to display a table view and an ui button on my home page

**How do I add new class for my home page in phone gap app?**

Comment: i used default html page, already loaded while starting the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did my first PhoneGap Application, I also used Sencha Touch which is a great framework that provides Interface component like buttons, panels and lists

You can find all these components in the [Kitchen Sink](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/list)

Here's a tutorial on [how to start with Sencha Touch 2](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2)

You can also find a tutorial on [how to create a Sencha Touch 2 app](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-in-5-minutes-or-less/)

Hope this helps

Comment: does we need to down load Sencha Touch as separate frame work which cane be used in our phone gap app...?

or need to instal as seperate tempale like phonegapbasedaplication

Comment: Thank u very much, can u please provide links / help.  to down load and how to use in iphone phone gap applications

Comment: Yes, you need to download it and add it to your application as a js file. I added another tutorial on how to start –